# Divergence Formal Definition Meaning of $\lim_{R_{(x,y,z)} \to 0}$ of Region R

Tags: limits, definition, surface-integrals

A formal definition of divergence for 3 dimensions is the following,

$$\lim_{R_{(x,y,z)} \to 0}\frac{1}{|R_{(x,y,z)}|}\iint_SF\cdot\hat{n}D_\sum$$

My question is and the part I do not understand is R going to 0. What is the role of the volume (region) going to 0? What is it's purpose and reason for existing and how does it relate to the flux integral?

From my point of view, the region R seems to be an arbitrary concept that does not add any value to the formula and makes it more complex than it needs to be. I hope someone can help me understand it.

Comment: This is not "the" formal definition of divergence. It is "a" formal definition of divergence. There are others. The point is trying to define divergence geometrically, that is, without having to rely on a particular coordinate system. FYI - the tag "divergent-integrals" is about integrals that do not converge. It has nothing to do with the divergence of a vector field.

Comment: The probably mean the limit over rectangles with centre $(x,y,z)$ whose side lengths tend to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition is motivated by Gauss's theorem:
$$\iiint_R \text{div}(\mathbf F)\,dV = \iint_S \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n\,dA$$
Where $S = \partial R$ is the surface of the region $R$ and $\mathbf n$ is the unit outward normal to $S$.

Intuitively, if we think of $\mathbf F$ as being the steady-state flow of some ethereal incompressible fluid, the value of the divergence at a point $p, \text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p$ is the amount of fluid that is emerging at $p$ (negative if the fluid is disappearing at $p$). The theorem says that the amount of fluid emerging over the entire region $R$ is equal to the amount of fluid flowing through the surface of $R$.

If $\text{div}(\mathbf F)$ is continuous, then for each $p$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $R_\epsilon$ of $p$ such that if $q \in R_\epsilon$, then $|\text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_q - \text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p| < \epsilon$ and therefore $$(\text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p -\epsilon)\text{Vol}(R_\epsilon)\le \iiint_{R_\epsilon} \text{div}(\mathbf F)\,dV \le (\text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p +\epsilon)\text{Vol}(R_\epsilon)$$ or 
$$\left| \text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p - \dfrac 1{\text{Vol}(R_\epsilon)}\iiint_{R_\epsilon} \text{div}(\mathbf F)\,dV \right |\le \epsilon$$
Plugging in Gauss's Law:
$$\left| \text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p - \dfrac 1{\text{Vol}(R_\epsilon)}\iint_{\partial R_\epsilon} \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n\,dA \right |\le \epsilon$$

More generally, the same holds for any neighborhoods of $p$ smaller than $R_\epsilon$.

So the idea here is to turn this around and use it to define $\text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p$ in the first place:

> $\text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p = L$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $R_\epsilon$ of $p$ such that for all neighborhood regions $R$ of $p$ with $R \subseteq R_\epsilon$,
>   $$\left| L - \dfrac 1{\text{Vol}(R)}\iint_{\partial R} \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n\,dA \right |\le \epsilon$$

or written in a limit notation:
$$\text{div}(\mathbf F)\vert_p = \lim_{R \to p} \dfrac 1{\text{Vol}(R)}\iint_{\partial R}\mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n\,dA$$

The integral $\iint_{\partial R}\mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n\,dA$ depends not only on the behavior of $\mathbf F$ at $p$, but on its behavior over the entire region. By letting $R \to p$, one removes the impact of $\mathbf F$'s behavior at other points, leaving only the behavior at $p$.

This is entirely analogous to the definition of the derivative itself, where the limit is taken to turn the average rate of change over an interval into the rate of change of the function at a single point.

Comment: So in essence, $Vol(R)$ translates to local or micro behaviour around a point and the double integral translates to global or macro behaviour of the region? Did I say that correctly? Correct me if I am wrong. So I think the next natural question to ask should be, why do you need both the local and global descriptions of the divergence? Is one of them not enough to describe divergence?

Comment: That is not at all correct. The double integral is over the surface of $R$. As $R$ shrinks towards $p$, so does that surface. It is not "global". We are only looking at its value when the entire surface is close to $p$. (Note that the limit notation is not fully descriptive. $\text{Vol}(R) \to 0$ in and of itself does not require the region to become fully close to $p$. This is why I also gave the definition of that limit, which does spell out that the entire region $R$ (including its surface) must be in shrinking neighborhoods of $p$.)

Comment: Actually, looking at the notation, I decided it would be better to just say $R\to p$ instead of $\text{Vol}(R) \to 0$. I was thinking your question was saying the volume went to $0$ and was imitating that. But it is better to think of it as the limit as the region $R$ shrinks towards the point $p$.

Comment: So when $R \to 0$, that is just to counteract the value of the other points so you get the value around $p$ only?

Comment: "Counteract" is not quite the correct word, but it is to eliminate the impact of the other points, since they all pass outside the region and no longer contribute to the integral.